# Using $expand in Graph API query with multiple attributes?

Tags: azure, graph, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to $expand multiple attributes. For example:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me?$expand=memberOf,manager

This will result in an error.

> The result of parsing $expand contained at least 2 items, but the
>   maximum allowed is 1.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty explicit. Maximum allowed is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to document($expand section) :

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/overview/query_parameters

> > If you query on the [user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) resource, you can use $expand to get the properties of only one child object or collection at a time.

And [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/96) is a discussion about same topic :

> > However, specific entities may still have limits and for users it is still limited to a single expanded navigation. That is not expected to change.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: I know this is quite an old question, but for anyone ending here in the future:

It is possible (in some cases) with the following syntax:

```
$expand=relation1($select=id,name),relation2($expand=relation2a($select=id))
```

It is difficult to determine where expands will work since the documentation is quite evasive, but I have made the above work successfully.
Perhaps the missing piece for your case is to specify the inner query paremeters in your expands?

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADFjM...ATjA9VZAAA=?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'string 0x1a'),microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event
```

Comment: it is not clear, what is relation2a and relation2.

Comment: @fawzib The relations are child (related) objects. e.g. if the API lets the child `manager` object be queried, you could use `$expand=manager($select=id,name)`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http#expand-parameter

Unfortunately, it doesn't let you bypass that error, which I'm getting for a completely different Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

The same seems to be true for a Group, you cannot get the Owners and Members at the same time!
This is very limiting so you need to make multiple calls to get the information.